OpenSearch Failed to parse date field with format epoch_millis
I have a OISI pipeline to connect DynamoDB with OpenSearch. The creationTime field in my DynamoDB pipeline is using the standard milliseconds timestamp format and is of type number.
When the pipeline runs I get the following error:
Preview of field's value: '1.717692837E12' caused by failed to parse date field [1.717692837E+12] with format [epoch_millis] caused by Failed to parse with all enclosed parsers

I have trouble figuring out what the problem is, because as far as I can tell the value it is showing me in the error is a valid epoch_millis timestamp.
